# Не помещается асинхронная функция в переменную telegram bot aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я хочу поместить функцию в главную переменную, где они будут лежать, чтобы потом сделать таких функций много и вызвать их рандомно методом `random.choice(testbb)`, а в самих функциях будет желать текст вместе с инлайн кнопками и отправка их ботом.

Но когда я помещаю функцию в переменную вылазит ошибка:

```
D:\papka\user\testpy>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\papka\user\testpy\test.py", line 36, in <module>
    testbb = [asyncio.run(test(message))]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\papka\user\testpy\test.py", line 34, in test
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, b)
AttributeError: module 'aiogram.types.message' has no attribute 'chat'
```

А вот код:

```
from aiogram.types import message
from aiogram import types, executor
import asyncio
import random

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
import logging

TOKEN = 'токен я скрыл'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(testbb))

async def test(message: types.Message):
    b = 'это текст пример.\nЕсли это сработает я буду рад'
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, b)

testbb = [asyncio.run(test(message))]

if __name__ == "__main__":
   executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True,)
```

Comment: Тут уже начиная с идеи всё неправильно. Объясните пожалуйста, для чего вы хотите вызывать случайную функцию, и чем они отличаются друг друга, что эту логику нельзя в одну функцию вывести?

Comment: я хочу чтобы в переменной `testbb` лежали списком функции, а в самих функциях будет текст вопрос от бота и инлайн кнопки ответа к этому тексту. И самое главное чтобы каждый раз когда вызывалась эта  переменная методом ` random.choice(testbb) ` отправлялся рандомно из ` testbb ` одна функция в которой будет желать текст вопроса и инлайн кнопки ответы к вопросу

Comment: Я нашел пример того что я хочу ``` bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(fruit)) fruit = ['яблоко', 'банан', 'груша', 'персик']``` Но надо чтобы за место яблок, банан и тд были функции

Comment: В списках нельзя хранить функции. Создайте в БД таблицу, где хранятся все вопросы и ответы, и вызывайте рандомный вопрос в боте в любом месте, не нужно так всё усложнять :)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! ;) Сам бы я не догадался до этого способа, вы меня очень сильно выручили